# Django Public URL Rewrite

Tags: python, django, .htaccess

I am deploying a Django application to an environment which requires a user login for everything by default, however allows you to specific URLs you want to display without a login if you start the URL with `/public`, for instance `/public/forums` (this is a security measure to have everything protected by default and explicitly define what should be publically accessible).

I decided just to prefix all the URLs I want public in `urls.py` with `/public`. This works, however I don't want `/public` to be shown. I added to the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

however, my server is coming back with `LimitInternalRecursion`.

How can I fix this to achieve a URL without public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` is being triggered by your `RewriteRule`. That is, you are rewriting to a URL that fires your rewrite, hence the recursion error. This is because your regular expression in `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]` is catching everything, even `/public/forums/`. Check out this saved example: https://regex101.com/r/dI8cH4/1. And try getting a simpler rewrite to work first (like to your landing/home page):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /public/ http://example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, let me research and test this out.